# Read Spark output in Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a Spark dataframe that I get after some processing in Python that I am saving (as a CSV) to my local disk, the output obviously looks something like:

```
/output
 |
 | _SUCCESS
 | part-00000
```

I am wondering, how can I read this output and print it in Python?

With a regular file I can do something like:

```
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

But that doesnt work with Spark outputs since it is outputted as a folder.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the type of the output file? Your question says `.csv` but you're trying to open a `.txt`, and you've posted the console output instead of the file output.

Comment: Also, post the code, it's hard to tell how to open the file without knowing how are you saving the file.